# AngularJS ng-repeat not displaying data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array inside of my controller that I'm tried to iterate into a table inside of my view template. Inside of the console, I can see the array objects but inside my table, I only see the rows without the data being displayed.

HTML Template:

```
<div class="availability-list-table" ng-controller="InventoryController">
<table class="table availability-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{items.qty}}</td>
        <td>{{items.item}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
    app.controller('InventoryController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = [
        {
            item: 'Blue Moon Pint',
            qty: 50,
        },
        {
            item: 'Bud Light Pint',
            qty: 50,
        },
        {
            item: 'Sprite',
            qty: 30,
        },
        {
            item: 'Coke',
            qty: 100
        }
    ];
}]);
```

### How the table looks:

### [image: How table looks:]

### This is what I can see inside of the console:

[image: This is what I can see inside of the console]

Comment: Maybe `<td>{{item.qty}}</td>` instead of `items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through items: `item in items`.

Try `item.qty` and `item.item` instead:

```
<div class="availability-list-table" ng-controller="InventoryController">
<table class="table availability-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{item.qty}}</td>
        <td>{{item.item}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```